# django: user activation during email confirmation

Tags: python, django, django-views

Unfortunately. user is not going to be activate
please someone help me in that ,thank you

views.py:

```
code = random.randint(1000, 9999)
def register_view(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        username = request.POST['username']
        password = request.POST['password']
        password1 = request.POST['password1']
        email = request.POST['email']
        global user
        user = User(email=email, username=username)
        user.set_password(password)
    elif:
         ...
    else:
         user.is_active = False
         user.save()
         return redirect('email_activation/')
```

again views.py another def

```
def email_activation(request):
if request.method == "POST":
    global code
    email_activation = request.POST['email_activation']
    if str(email_activation) == str(code):
        user.is_active = True
        return redirect('account')
    else:
        ...
```

please help me

Comment: You never save the user.

Comment: @Sayse No, I hid that part

Comment: Hid it where? you have a return statement directly after setting the active flag.

Comment: @Sayse i thought it's not important, because its not part of my problem, but i edited it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After you do:

```
user.is_active = True
```

write this line to save your `is_active` field on your `user` instance:

```
user.save()
```